# Battlefield - Carl Gustav policy

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

In Battlefield Bad Company 2 some server tend to ban the Carl Gustav weapon.

Could someone explain this kind of policy? What are the reason for this exclusion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a quite notorious weapon, and like the Grenade Launcher Attachment (a.k.a. Noob-Tube) in Modern Warfare 2, quite deadly against infantry. Since it does not lose elevation, you can snipe anything from the far end of the map, if you know where to shoot.

So, beginners, as they get hold of the weapon, abuse Carl Gustav, and get on other people's nerves. This causes imbalances in some people's opinion, yadda yadda, so they, as admins of their server, forbid the weapon as a rule.

It's a subjective issue and there is no scientific reasoning behind it. But I sense it has to do with getting killed by a weapon which requires no aiming skills whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the Bora already answered the specific question, but I'd like to write more about it.

Basically so called [**noobtubing**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=noob%20tube) is using grenade launcher or rocked launcher as your **primary** weapon. Some rookies don't even bother to use their rifles/SMGs at all, they just blast away with rockets. So there are many servers that have rule `no AT on inf` (no anti-tank rockets attacks on infantry). CG is particularly loathed, as it has significant splash damage, thus can kill infantry even with very poor aiming. At the same time it's weakest of all rocket launchers in it's anti-tank role. Also, on regular (i.e. non-hardcore) servers, you don't inflict team damage, thus shooting rockets into mixed groups is not penalized and can result in kill. Thus some players feel frustrated when they get killed by random rocket spam.

Personally I prefer hardcore servers. As rockets leave very visible trail, on such servers noobtubers are naturally eliminated. And actually one of my favorite servers, there was a poll, after which it was decided to have it explicitly allowed.